# Dspace change from postgresql to oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, dspace

Some knows the proccess to install or update dspace with Oracle database, i have problems with my dspace 4.2, i installed with postgresql without any problems, but when y try to change to oracle y have the next error:

```
build_webapps_wars:

check_geolite:

init_geolite:
     [java] 2015-10-23 17:18:58,899 INFO  org.dspace.core.ConfigurationManager @ Loading system provided config property (-Ddspace.configuration): config/dspace.cfg
     [java] 2015-10-23 17:18:58,919 INFO  org.dspace.core.ConfigurationManager @ Using default log4j provided log configuration.  If unintended, check your dspace.cfg for (log.init.config)
     [java] Started: 1445638738887
     [java] Ended: 1445638744119
     [java] Elapsed time: 5 secs (5232 msecs)
     [java] 2015-10-23 17:19:04,573 INFO  org.dspace.core.ConfigurationManager @ Loading system provided config property (-Ddspace.configuration): config/dspace.cfg
     [java] 2015-10-23 17:19:04,594 INFO  org.dspace.core.ConfigurationManager @ Using default log4j provided log configuration.  If unintended, check your dspace.cfg for (log.init.config)
     [java] 2015-10-23 17:19:30,184 INFO  org.dspace.search.DSIndexer @ Updating and Cleaning Index
     [java] Started: 1445638744638
     [java] Ended: 1445638770497
     [java] Elapsed time: 25 secs (25859 msecs)
     [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
     [java]     at org.dspace.search.DSIndexer.cleanIndex(DSIndexer.java:604)
     [java]     at org.dspace.search.DSIndexer.main(DSIndexer.java:507)

BUILD FAILED
/build/dspace-4.3-src-release/dspace/target/dspace-build/build.xml:968: Java returned: 1

Total time: 14 minutes 43 seconds
```

I Use oracle 11g XE , and i have the same problem testing with an oracle 11g EnterPrise Edition, my dspace.cfg is correctly with de db.name ant the driver with oracle, ifsomeone than can helpme with the error please.

Comment: That error message doesn't seem to have anything to do with Oracle. It looks like the Lucene index is trying to clean itself out and is failing. My guess is you are installing DSpace on top of an existing instance, and there may be a permissions issue with Lucene or something.  Please provide more information on what you are trying to achieve and the commands you are actually running.

Comment: I`m running th command ant fresh_install to install it in oracle

Comment: Did you previously install DSpace on this same machine?  The NullPointerException on that line seems to imply that a Lucene index *already exists* on that machine, and the "fresh_install" script is having difficulty cleaning the existing Lucene index.  Here's the line in the code where that NPE occurs:
https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-4_x/dspace-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/search/DSIndexer.java#L604

The "ant fresh_install" command will only succeed if DSpace does NOT yet exist in the location specified by "dspace.dir" in the dspace.cfg file.

Comment: Yes  i have Dspace already installed in PostgreSql but what command i need to use in order to change to an empty oracle database. Thanks

Comment: That question doesn't make sense to me. If DSpace is installed into one directory and is using Postgres from that directory, then you are better off either *deleting* that old DSpace installation, or creating a *new* directory for your DSpace on Oracle.  Part of the issue sounds like you are installing an Oracle-backend DSpace overtop of an existing PostgreSQL-backend DSpace, and that could run into strange issues.